# Zina in Islam as a homosexual

Tags: zina, homosexuality

I am full aware LGBT relationships are haram, but nowadays, there are gay Muslims who are married.

Would it still be considered Zina if a gay Muslim has intercourse when married?
It’s not like they’re having intercourse when single.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not an Islamic scholar, here's my opinion.

According to the Islam, only form of (valid) marriage is between men and women. Therefore, from an Islamic point of view, marriage of homosexual Muslims are not valid. Hence, their intercourse is considered extramarital (zina).

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer 

Comment: @Ten. Sure thing. If you believe this answers your question correctly, please accept it as answer.